# Busca profunda em tabelas

Tags: jquery, html5, algoritmo-de-busca

Preciso buscar um valor , só que tenho um problema, tenho que pesquisar em 3 tabelas diferentes para achar , e quando eu achar devo direcionar o foco para a DIV onde está tabela está. Eu consigo fazer essa busca com uma tabela tranquilamente, mas com 3 tabelas em 3 divs diferentes não estou conseguindo! Alguém sabe uma forma de realizar essa busca ? Obrigado.

Segue uma imagem do meu cenario, cada `tab` tem uma tabela dentro com os valores. Precisaria buscar o valor e falar em qual tabela e div e também evidenciar esse valor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Codigo da minha busca simples.

```
$(function(){
$(".input-search").keyup(function(){
    //pega o css da tabela 
    var tabela = $(this).attr('alt');
    if( $(this).val() != ""){
        $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").hide();
          $("."+tabela+" td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() +"')").parent("tr").show();
         } else{
        $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").show();
       }
    }); 
   });
   $.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array) {
      return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() ||       "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}
    });
```

Comment: Pode nos mostrar o que esteve tentando pf?

Comment: Sim , vou postar o codigo da busca com uma tabela , e uma imagem da interface também para entenderem melhor

Comment: Atualizei a questão